# Taylor series around $x = 0$ of $f(x) = \int_0^x\frac{dy}{1+y^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor series around $x = 0$ of $f(x) = \int_0^x\frac{dy}{1+y^4}$ and its radius of convergence.

It seems like one ought to take the Taylor series of the integrand, and then integrate the result. It also seems like one could substitute $u=y^4$ and then

$$\frac{1}{1+y^4} = \frac{d}{du}\ln(1+u)$$

so we can take the Taylor series of $\ln(1+u)$ to be

$$u-\frac{1}{2}u^2 + \frac{1}{3}u^3 + \ldots$$

Hence, we plug in $y^4$ and get

$$y^4 - \frac{1}{2}y^{16} + \frac{1}{3}y^{64} + \ldots$$

Do I need to multiply this by $du = 4y^3$? Is this the right way to approach the problem?

Comment: The subsitution you attempt just makes things more complicated. Isn't is much easier to simply expand $\frac{1}{1+y^4} = 1-y^4 + y^8 - y^{12} + \ldots$ and integrate termwise? The expansion of $\frac{1}{1+y^4}$ follows from $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$ by taking $x = -y^4$.

Comment: @Winther That absolutely makes more sense. Then I get the Taylor expansion to be $x - \frac{1}{5}x^5 + \frac{1}{9}x^9 - ...$

Comment: That looks correct.

Comment: @Winther Bingo,write it up as an answer so you can get points for it. Why would you make such a crazy substitution when there's a much more obvious and simple one?